# Recognizing QR codes for URLs without http(s) scheme in Python using Pyzbar

Tags: python

I need to recognize QR codes from a webcam, which I have successfully done using [Pyzbar](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/). However, the problem is that it does not recognize any QR codes whose URLs don't have a http(s) scheme.

My code can recognize QR codes that encode `https://www.google.com` but not `www.google.com`.

Comment: What have you tried already? Please show your current code also.

Comment: Www.google.com is a hostname not a URL.